# routing in laravel while submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just started laravel . I was able to fetch the data from mysql table but i was  unable to post data. I am confused on defining route for  post url

MODEL : Entry.php

---

```
<?php

class Entry extends Eloquent {

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'entries';

}
```

CONTROLLER :EntriesController.php

---

```
class EntriesController extends BaseController {

        # Handles "GET /" request
        public function getIndex()
        {
            return View::make('home')->with('entries', Entry::all());
        }

        # Handles "POST /"  request
        public function postIndex()
        {
            // get form input data
    $entry = array(
        'username' => Input::get('frmName'),
        'email'    => Input::get('frmEmail'),
        'comment'  => Input::get('frmComment'),
    );

    // save the guestbook entry to the database
    Entry::create($entry);

    return Redirect::to('/');

        }

}
```

VIEW : entry.blade.php

---

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Laravel Guestbook</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    @foreach($entries as $entry)
      <p>{{ $entry->comment }}</p>
      <p>Posted on {{ $entry->created_at }}  by
         <a href="mailto:{{ $entry->email }}">{{ $entry->username}}</a>
      </p><hr />
    @endforeach

    <form action="submit/" method="POST">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmName" value="" size="30" maxlength="50"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="frmEmail" value="" size="30" maxlength="100"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Comment</td>
                <td><textarea name="frmComment" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
                    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</BODY>


</HTML>
```

ROUTES

---

```
Route::get('/', 'EntriesController@getIndex');
Route::get('submit', 'EntriesController@postIndex');
```

On homepage i can easily pull the records from db but when i try to post new record it will show the error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using blade, you can start using the blade syntaxis which will make it probably a lot more easy to create your forms.

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'submit')) }}
// The 'url' => 'submit' wil refer to your route and fetch your postFunction you made.
// You can here setup your form components...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**A reference for creating the components:**

http://laravel.com/docs/html

Note:
**Don't forget to use the Laravel validators when checking your input in your controller.**

http://laravel.com/docs/validation